# Call methods from delegated class

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my LocationController.h

```
// protocol for sending location updates to another view controller
@protocol LocationControllerDelegate
@required
- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation*)location;
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations;
@end

@interface LocationController : NSObject  {

   CLLocationManager* locationManager;
   CLLocation* location;
   __weak id delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager* locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation* location;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id  delegate;

+ (LocationController*)sharedLocationController; // Singleton method

@end
```

In the LocationController.m

```
static LocationController* sharedCLDelegate = nil;

@implementation LocationController
@synthesize locationManager, location, delegate;

- (id)init
{
  self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
       self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
       self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
       self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 10.0f;
       self.locationManager.headingFilter = 5;

       [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
 }
  return self;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark CLLocationManagerDelegate Methods
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager
   didFailWithError:(NSError*)error
{

}

#pragma mark - Singleton implementation in ARC
+ (LocationController *)sharedLocationController
{
static LocationController *sharedLocationControllerInstance = nil;
static dispatch_once_t predicate;
dispatch_once(&predicate, ^{
    sharedLocationControllerInstance = [[self alloc] init];
});
return sharedLocationControllerInstance;
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
@synchronized(self) {
    if (sharedCLDelegate == nil) {
        sharedCLDelegate = [super allocWithZone:zone];
        return sharedCLDelegate;  // assignment and return on first allocation
    }
}
return nil; // on subsequent allocation attempts return nil
}

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
return self;
}
```

I then want to call one of these methods in another ViewController, so in my viewDidLoad I set the delegate `[LocationController sharedLocationController].delegate = self;` I then want to call a method from the LocationController class

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
//How can I call the CLLocation from the LocationController class so I don't have to create a new one
CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];
}
```

Also how do I call this method in the viewDidLoad?

**So my question is how can I reuse the CLLocation from the LocationController class and how can I then implement the didUpdateLocations method in my ViewController?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose if you want to call the

```
- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation*)location;
```

method from the `LocationController`, you can use the delegate object.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
   if (self.delegate != nil)
   {
      CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];
      [self.delegate locationUpdate:location];
   }
}
```

Comment: What does _delegate need to be set as? Getting undefined error.

Comment: @joshuahornby10: `self.delegate` you declared the delegate in `LocationController` right ?

Comment: I have, [LocationController sharedLocationController].delegate = self;

Comment: @joshuahornby10: from the LocationController, you need to call the LocationControllerDelegate's delegate method of the view controller right ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean can you give a code example? thanks.

Comment: I got this error: Property 'delegate' not found on object of type 'JHHomeViewController *'

Comment: @joshuahornby10: The above code should be in `LocationControllerDelegate` not in `JHHomeViewController`

Comment: Ah right ok, final question then: how do I call this method in JHHomeViewController?

Comment: If you set the `[LocationController sharedLocationController].delegate = self;` in `JHHomeViewController` Whenever the `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations` in the `LocationController` called, it will call the delegate's (JHHomeViewController) method.

Answer (score 0):

hey `didUpdateLocations` is a delegate method of CLLocationManager class it called itself for this you have to set CLLocation like this

```
@interface MapViewController : UIViewController < CLLocationManagerDelegate>
```